# Need assistance to create an inbound warehouse simulation?

Tags: anylogic

I need to create a simulation in which I model the flow if trucks into a warehouse. I do not need to see the inside of the warehouse, just model the current process of the trucks as they come into the warehouse. The typical process is that they come in, go to a weigh station and then make a "u turn" and then backup inorder to unload material, and then leave the premises. I have been playing around with anylogic for a couple of hours now, but have not made any actual progress.

Any help would be deeply appreciated!!!!!!! Thank you!!!!

Comment: Hi welcome to Stack Overflow. Your post doesn't contain a question, nor does it clearly explain your problem. Perhaps review [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips.

Comment: https://www.anylogic.com/resources/books/free-simulation-book-and-modeling-tutorials/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend completing the job shop tutorial. It teaches the basics of agent movement in the process modelling library.

Comment: You will not learn hot to do the truck movement wanted from the job shop tutorial (making a u turn and then backup)